# Laravel 5.2 validation check if value is not equal to a variable

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

In my instance one user is inviting another I would like to check if the user they are inviting is not themselves.

Thus I have two variables *incomming email* and *user->email*

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);
```

How can I add that validation rule to the validation call?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `not_in`, which allows you to specify a list of values to reject:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email|not_in:'.$user->email,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasted one hour to find the solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can use *`different:field`* according to the [laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-different)

For instanse in your requests validation:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'from' => 'required',
            'to' => 'required|different:from',
            'action' => 'required',
            'access' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

These two `from` and `to` should be different(not same).

Comment: `different:from` has small tricky moment, at least for laravel 5.8. The case is that if from will be `from='3'` and `to=3`, they will considered as different.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vlad Barseghyan mentioned in the accepted answer:

> The case is that if from will be from='3' and to=3, they will considered as different.

That's because of how the `different` validation rule compares the given fields. It uses strict comparison which leads to unexpected behavior in some cases when dealing with `integers`.

The `not_in` rule uses loose comparison and it can be used to accomplish the same behavior of `different` rule.

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'from' => 'required',
            'to' => 'required|not_in:' . $this->from,
            'action' => 'required',
            'access' => 'required'
        ];
    }


    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'to.not_in' =>
                'to and from should be different.'
        ];
    }
```