# Check if a string is "0" with Laravel validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

How can I check if a value of a string is "0" in Laravel 5.3?

Here's my validation rules before processing the data:

```
// I want them to be anything but "0". So "01", "1" etc. are all okay
$rules = [
    'state' => 'required',
    'city' => 'required',
];
```

As the data is passed as strings I cannot use min:1 for this.

I'm sorry if this have already been asked, but I cannot find an answer. Many thanks!

Comment: Clear more by giving example,  which input will be ok and which is not ?

Comment: Anything but "0" will be okay, so "01", "1", "abc" etc should all be allowed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$rules = [
    'state' => 'required|not_in:0',
    'city' => 'required|not_in:0',
];
```

Also, have a look at this:
[Laravel 5.2 validation check if value is not equal to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842487/laravel-5-2-validation-check-if-value-is-not-equal-to-a-variable)

Comment: Be careful of unintended behavior from lax type comparison. ```not_in``` uses PHP's ```in_array()``` with ```$strict = false```. This causes unexpected rule failures, e.g. ```city = "1E-1"``` would fail validation because ```(int) "1E-1" = 0```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use `regex` like:

```
$rules = array(
    'field'=> 'regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/'
);
```

regex:pattern

The field under validation must match the given regular expression.

**Note:** When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

[Refrence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've looked into regex, what would the pattern be to disallow "0" in this case? Anything other than the string "0" should pass the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to check if the price is greater than 0. This method helped me.

Laravel Doc: [gt:field](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-gt)

```
'buy_price'  => 'required|integer|gt:0',
'sell_price' => 'required|integer|gt:buy_price',
```

Error: "The buy price field must be greater than 0. (and 1 more error)"